# GeoLocation giving "Permission was revoked" in Chrome and not other browsers even though I can't retrieve location data in any

Tags: javascript, reactjs, geolocation, navigator

I am working with the Geolocation API in a React project and on calling the API, I am receiving a callback error message that permission is revoked. I have toggled on and off the location popup and also reset the location to be available for all applications in my OS settings. I tested this on Chrome, Brave and Edge with the location access allowed. On all browsers, I have no location data available but in Chrome, I get a "Permission was revoked" error also.

I am trying to save the values of the latitude and longitude into a React state.

```
   const [location, setLocation] = useState({
     latitude: "",
     longitude: "",
   });
  

  function successCallback(position) {
    const latitude = position.coords.latitude;
    const longitude = position.coords.longitude;
    setLocation(prevValue => ({
      ...prevValue,
      latitude,
      longitude,
    }));
  }

  function errorCallback(error) {
    console.log("Error", error);
  }

  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(successCallback, errorCallback);
```

When I console log the location state inside the `successCallback` function, I have no data, calling it inside of my main render returns just an object with empty values set to the `latitude` and `longitude` in the `location` state.

My problem is that, how do I get the location data to be retrieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this issue earlier today but restarting Chrome should fix it. To be sure, try reseting data + permissions for the page you're having that issue before restarting Chrome.

You can do that though `chrome://settings/content/all` and searching for the URL or though the Lock icon next to the url

Comment: Thanks. I have restarted my machine. Currently, it is no more displaying the "Permission was revoked" error but "Network error. Check DevTools for more information." And there is no indicator of anything that could have gone wrong in the DevTools.

Comment: It is now working. After restarting my machine, got a "Network error" in the console. I connected to the internet and it was working normally.